# Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftMetalKit.dylib in UITests in Xcode10

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode10

When running my UITests Target in Xcode10, I now get:

Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftMetalKit.dylib . <--- (Library varies)

Referenced from: ../MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/Frameworks/Hero.framework/Hero <-- (Framework varies, all installed with Cocoapods 1.6.0beta1)

Reason: image not found)

My regular target works fine. My Regular target and UITests targets both have "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" set to Yes, though I noticed the Pods Project and frameworks have this set to No.

Things I've tried:

- Cleaning project, deleting derived data, and rebuilding project
- Verifying my code signing is working
- Setting "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to Yes on the Pods Project and frameworks.
- adding @rpath to the Runpath Search paths for the UI Tests Target

So far nothing has worked. Anyone else encountering this issue or have insight into what might help?

EDIT:
Thanks @matt for pointing me in the direction of the related isue.
I tried importing UIKit and recreating target, both to no avail.
Importing the specific frameworks (i.e. Hero) or the libraries (i.e. MetalKit) in one of my UITest targets allows it to build, but mysteriously my other UITest target will still not build due to libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport (referenced by Alamofire) not building.
Still not sure if this is due to my Cocoapods setup (All my targets including UITest targets import all pods, which I think should be unnecessary but I get missing frameworks for my pods if I don't), but the exact same setup worked fine prior to XCode 10.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879799/xcode-7-ui-testing-with-cocoapods-fails-on-device

Comment: Simplest solution is probably just copy the UI test file code, delete the UI test target and all its files, make a completely new UI test target, and paste in the code. I often have to do that after an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the followings:

Copy from your TARGETS from your basic project let say 'sample_app' > Build Phases the section **[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks**.

Now In the UITest TARGETS, let say 'sample_app_UITests' create a new **Run Script** and copy everything.

Clean/Build

Answer (score 0):

Setting the workspace setting to Legacy build fixed it for me: File > Workspace Settings > Build System: Legacy Build System